# static_assert and class templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static-assert

I have a problem with the `static_assert` feature. When I instantiate a class template directly, everything works as expected. But when I pass it as a parameter for the different class template, `static_assert` does not work.

```
template <int X>
class A{
    static_assert(X == 0, "X != 0");
};

template <class T>
class B{

};

B<A<1>> b;           // Static assert does not work
A<1>    a;           // error: static assertion failed: X != 0
```

**EDIT**

Thanks all for the answers. Is there a way to explicitly instantiate A without creation of A instances / inheriting from A? I was trying this:

```
template <int X>
class A{
    static_assert(X == 0, "X != 0");
};

template <class T>
class B;

template <template <int X> class T, int X>
class B<T<X>>{
    template class T<X>;
};
```

But this is incorrect.

Comment: `B<T>` never instantiates `T`. The static assertion only fires when a template specialization is instantiated.

Comment: @KerrekSB: ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `B<A<1>> b;`, `A<1>` is only used as template argument, which doesn't cause [implicit instantiation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Implicit_instantiation) of class template `A`, then the `static_assert` inside `A`'s definition won't be triggered.

> When code refers to a template in context that requires a completely defined type, or when the completeness of the type affects the code, and this particular type has not been explicitly instantiated, implicit instantiation occurs. For example, when an object of this type is constructed, but not when a pointer to this type is constructed.

On the other hand, for `A<1> a;`, `A<1>` is required to be a complete type (to construct `a`), then implicit instantiation happens, `static_assert` is fired.

**EDIT**

You can use `sizeof` (which requires the type to be complete) to cause the implicit instantiation and fire the `static_assert`. e.g.

```
template <class T>
class B{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) > 0, "static_assert for implicit instantiation");
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly instantiate the A template class in the body of B without creation of A instance / inheriting from A?
I do know about this syntax:
       template class A<1>;
But I can't use this in the B body.

Comment: @valentin Answer revised.

Answer (score 3):

Your class template `B` doesn't do anything with its `T`, so its `T` isn't instantiated.

Thus "nothing happens" to the `A<1>` in `B<A<1>>`.

If you had a member `T a` inside `B` then you'd get the assertion failure.